# How can I sniff ethernet iOS traffic

Tags: ios, jailbreak, sniffing, usb-camera

I have a USB camera that does work with iOS devices on a specific application made by the manufacturer. When connected, it creates an ethernet interface for which I'm always assigned the same IP address and then when launching the app the camera shows up.

There is no documentation for this device or known API to make it work on other devices or apps.

How can I monitor the traffic between the device and the USB camera in order to find out endpoints (wether HTTP/HTTPS or not) to be able to use the camera on other devices?

The virtual network created by MacOS is (at first glance) not the good approach because my iOS device port is already in use by the USB camera.

I'm interested in both non-jailbreak and jailbreak ways of doing that.

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is Wireshark.

Comment: Of course, this is what could be cool to do in the end but the problem here is to get that traffic into WireShark :)